# Need solution for this simple responsive design requirement - moving DOM elements on breakpoints

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, adaptive-design

I have this doubt about the below responsive design.

As per the code below & shown in js fiddle as well, by default, on desktop, I want the anchor to display both "Name" & "Login Time". And when the resolution goes below 480px, "Login Time" shouldnt be displayed in the anchor, instead it should show up as the first list item in the ul.
So, to achieve this, I created an extra li as first element, which is hidden, when on desktop and as soon as resolution goes below 480px, it shows up and the "Login Time" in anchor is hidden.

My doubt is that, is this the right solution to get this thing, as for this, I need to duplicate the "Login Time" html in 2 places, although one is hidden at a time.

http://jsfiddle.net/M7J4q/2/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href="#">
        <p>Name</p>
        <p>Login Time</p>
    </a>
    <ul>
        <li>Login Time</li>
        <li>Help</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Log out</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a {text-decoration:none; display:block; background:#333; color:#fff}
p{ margin:0px;}
ul{list-style-type:none; padding:0; background:#999}
ul li:first-child {display:none}

@media (max-width:480px){
a p:last-child {display:none}
ul li:first-child {display:block}
}
```

Comment: "If it ain't broke don't fix it" - Abraham Lincoln

Comment: @Abraham - would it mean that this should be good to go, if things are working fine. Plz confirm.

Answer (score 1):

According to me this is perfect solution.
And as far as I know, there is no other way to achieve this (only with CSS).

If you wish to use jQuery for this, it can be achieved using [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

I prefer this CSS solution over jQuery.

Yes, you do have to keep the same code at two places but in such kind of functionality, it is acceptable.